# How to use ask open file name with open function then take that file into another function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm making a program that takes two file comparing them then find the percentage of similarity,now I'm having hard time to take the file name THEN Pass IT TO open function to read it THEN PASSING THE DATA Generated into another function ,it shows me that error

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: ''
```

my code is

```
Copied_File = ''
def Click_Copy():
  global Copied_File
  Copied_File = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='C:/Users/%s' % user)
  directory = os.path.split(Copied_File)[0]
  return Copied_File
with open((Copied_File), 'r')as file_1:
  file1_data = file_1.read()
  View_copied_File.insert(0.0, file1_data)


btn_Copy = ttk.Button(text="Open Copied File",command=Click_Copy)
btn_Copy.place(x =10, y = 30, width=120, height=34)

View_copied_File= ScrolledText(Window_1, width=50, height=40,state = "normal")
View_copied_File.place(x =10, y = 70)
```

Comment: Ignoring the function, your codes defines `Copied_File` as an empty string and then tries to open that in the `with` statement. Since you don't call the function until later, reading fails. The error message even says so: `or filename: ''`

Comment: `Click_Copy` returns the filename. Where do yo think it returns it _to_?

Comment: I want to execute click copy when the button(btn_Copy) is pressed

Answer (score 0):

As @Stefans commented you, there is a problem when you tried to open the file `Copied_File` because by the moment you run the `with open((Copied_File), 'r')as file_1:`, you have `Copied_File =`.

This means:

`with open((Copied_File), 'r')as file_1:` is equal to `with open('', 'r')as file_1:`

You defined `Click_Copy()` method but you never executed it. So you need to call that method before the `with` statement.

To resolve your problem, you may call the method directly:

```
...    
with open(Click_Copy(), 'r') as file_1:
   ...
```

Comment: I want to execute click copy when the button(btn_Copy) is pressed then pass that file name to the with open function

Comment: the answer that you provided me make the program open the ask open file dialogue as soon as i start the program not when i click the button